# Drawing lines for every row from a table

Tags: qgis, line

I would like to make a map showing all the train trips made by different users. I know how to make the difference between a single trip on a traject and many trips by using opacity.

For now I have data of every user between which stations they travelled and which route they took (Dijkstra's algorithm doesnt apply as some users take longer routes). The route is now an array but if it's easier to use in another format, feel free to say so. The core of the date I would like to use looks like this:

```
User | Route
Tim  | 1,2,5
Max  | 2,3,4
Ann  | 3,5,6
Jane | 4,3,2
...  | ...
```

Each number corresponds to a traject between 2 stations which the user travelled on. (see image) I would like to plot every time a traject is used by a user, a line on the map showing that traject. Of course the shape (a polyline) of each traject is available.

[image: Network example map]

How can I get from this table and list of shapes to a map which shows all trips made in QGIS?

Comment: what's the *Route* column's data type? array?

Comment: The route data type is indeed an array, but this can be changed when necessary.

Comment: thanks for the update. I forgot to ask: by 'table' do you mean the data is in a DB by any chance? if so, which one? PostgreSQL?

Comment: For now the table is an csv file, but of course this can be transformed to any other table/db format

Comment: many if not most file based formats have little to no support for array types, even SQLite. you will have to unnest (duplicate row for and with each array element) those arrays in some way; I don´t know if Excel can do that, a small script definetely could...but it would be dead simple using PostgreSQL/PostGIS. are you open to a (pure) SQL solution, including storing that data (and maybe even the geometries?) in the DB, to accumulate those values?